# Can I use response rates rather than raw data as input for ROC?

Tags: proc-r-package

I only have the summary statistics of the response rates at different criterion levels instead of the raw data. Can pROC take response rates as input to create ROC curves and conduct bootstrapping?

Comment: And also how to make a great R reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't do that. [No software can. Even if you have a few contingency table rather than one, this will still not be a valid ROC curve](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372236/what-is-the-formula-to-calculate-the-area-under-the-roc-curve-from-a-contingency).